# Android New Activity UI only loads after code is done

Tags: android, sockets

My main activity starts a new activity and supplies it with a string array of file paths. Like this:

```
Intent i = new Intent(getBaseContext(), upScreen.class);
i.putExtra("paths", selPhotos);
startActivity(i);
```

In the new activity I send one of the files at a time to a server via sockets while I update a progress bar. The thing is: the new activity's UI only load after the files were sent! So I can only see the progress bar complete.
How can I wait until my UI is fully initialized before I begin doing any transaction?

I do the socket commands asynchronously and I already tried putting the code that launches the thread which does the socket commands under onWindowFocusChanged but had no success.

Please help!

Comment: can you post your code whatever you tried

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have the uploads blocking the UI thread.  You'll need to use an `AsyncTask` or other form of new thread to do the uploads while the only work going on in the UI thread is to show the `Activity`'s GUI and update the progress bar.

The documents for `AsyncTask` use a downloader example, which easily extends to your uploader requirement: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Comment: My uploads are already done in a new thread. I will try to adapt the reference example.

Comment: It's almost certain the UI thread is blocking somehow in onCreate or onStart of the new activity.  Without seeing its code, I can't say more. If you're not successful, post code for the new activity.  The calling code alone isn't much help.